# Convert a bitmap to a json file in a png format?

Tags: c++, json, bitmap, png

I have a json file that is holding some information, along with that, I would like an image(preferably as a string) to b a png representation of the bitmap object so it is easily recoverable. What are the steps to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So you want to [convert a chunk of binary data into a textual representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)?

Comment: I don't even know the process so I haven't run into any problems yet, so I need to know where to start. That is why I asked, what are the steps to do this

Comment: At least give a concrete example of your inputs and expected outputs.